# Getting this error in spring boot: The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to spring.  In attempt to learn it I was following an example of Josh Long to create an OAuth server.  The difference between his example and the code that I'm working on is that I'm trying to use a MySQL rather than in memory database.  I'll leave relevant files in the post.

Thanks in advance.

Oh, and here's the link to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoK5a99Bmjc

Here's my class that implements Repository

```
@Service
public class AccountRepositoryImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public AccountRepositoryImpl(AccountRepository accountRepository){
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return accountRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .map(account -> new User(account.getUsername(),
                        account.getPassword(), account.isActive(), account.isActive(), account.isActive(), account.isActive(),
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                        ))
                .orElseThrow(() ->new UsernameNotFoundException ("Couldn't find the username " + username + "!"));  
    }
}
```

Here's the Repository

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
    Optional<Account> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two parts do the exact same thing:

```
@Autowired
private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
```

and

```
public AccountRepositoryImpl(AccountRepository accountRepository){
    this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
}
```

When you added the @Autowired annotation above accountRepository, Spring  automatically injects an instance of AccountRepository into your AccountRepositoryImpl class. So you need to remove the 2nd selection because it most likely conflicts with the @Autowired annotation.

EDIT -----------------------------

```
@Component 
public class ApplicationStartUp implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @SuppressWarnings("null") 
    @Override 
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) { 
        Account account = new Account("sPatel", "Spring", true); 

        accountRepository.save(account); 
        return; 
    }

}
```

Comment: When I remove the constructor it gives me an error to initialize the Autowired variable.  When I initialize it to null I get another error: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at me.saurinpatel.ApplicationStartUp.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationStartUp.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
 at me.saurinpatel.ApplicationStartUp.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationStartUp.java:1) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: Can you try removing "final" from "private final AccountRepository accountRepository". Do not initialize it to null.

Comment: I removed the final keyword, which helped me by not initializing the variable but still getting this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at me.saurinpatel.ApplicationStartUp.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationStartUp.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
 at me.saurinpatel.ApplicationStartUp.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationStartUp.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)

Comment: I don't think that null pointer is being thrown by the code you provided. It is most likely caused somewhere else in the application.

Comment: You were right the null point was coming from another component that I wrote.  Which was supposed to insert some dummy data into the database at application start up.@Component
public class ApplicationStartUp 
implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  @SuppressWarnings("null")
@Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

    // here your code ...
   Account account = new Account("sPatel", "Spring", true);
   
   AccountRepository accountRepository = null;
   accountRepository.save(account);

    return;
  }
}

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Can you take a look at the comment above and tell me what I'm doing wrong there.  Thanks again!

Comment: In the comment above.. you wrote accountRepository = null;   then afterwards, you called accountRepository.save(account)     . Calling the save() method on something that is null will trigger a null pointer exception.

Comment: When I remove the null Eclipse gives me an error and wants me to initialize it.

Comment: You can inject accountRepository into your class instead. I edited my original answer at the very top to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

What is your implementation of `AccountRepository` interface?

If your are not provide implementation for `AccountRepository` spring could not initialize it.

Your fist `Exception` (dependencies form cycle) may be occurred if you **autowired** `AccountRepositoryImpl` in your implementation of `AccountRepository`.

What is your log content when `Exception` (The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle) is occurred ?